# Is the function one-to-one?

Tags: functions, proof-writing

Is the function $f: \mathbb R+ \to\mathbb R \\$ defined as $f(x) = \sqrt{x} + x + 2$ one-to-one?

I'm pretty sure the function is one to one but when I try to solve $f(x) = f(y)$ to $x = y$  I get suck at $\sqrt{x} + x = \sqrt{y} + y$ and don't know where to continue.

Thanks

Comment: Is it strictly increasing?

Comment: Note that $\sqrt x + x = \sqrt x(\sqrt x + 1)$...

Comment: You could prove that its derivative is positive. Then the original function must be an an increasing one.

Answer (score 2):

From your last expression, we have

$$\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y} = y - x = -(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y})(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})$$

If $x \neq y$, does that lead to a contradiction?